# Two Drop Down Menus

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I wish I could use jQuery, but this has to in JavaScript. I'd appreciate the help.
When "empty" (first drop down menu) is selected, I need all values from the second drop down menu (a, b, c).
When "1" is selected, I need just a, b.
When "2" is selected, I need just b, c.

*Nothing's wrong with the drop down menu. Just had to change the values. How would I fix this in JavaScript?*

First menu

```html
<onchange="first(this);>
<option value="empty"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

Second menu

```html
<id="second">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript written already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I would prefer is to set the style to none via CSS in JS. This way, the element still exists but it is just hidden from the viewer.

You can the get value of an element via `[element-here].value` and compare the to some value that you want. From there, you would select the second drop down option value you have and run `[element-here].style.display = "none"`

Another way that is more complicated that I would not recommend is to create and destroy elements entirely. Something like:

```
var x = document.createElement("option");
x.value = VALUE HERE;
parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode("TEXT HERE"))
```

Comment: Brilliant. My biggest issue was that every time I click anything in the first drop down menu, the second drop down menu values would disappear. However, I'm not very good with CSS... Could you go in just a tad bit deeper for me...?

Comment: Have you set up a listener to detect changes in the first dropdown? If not, the second dropdown may only update on execution but not again.

Another reason that the items may be disappearing is because I forgot to add code to "reenable" visibility after a new item in the first menu is selected, or maybe the wrong elements in the second drop down are being selected. To do that, have `[element-here].style.display = ""` instead of `"none"`.


For example:
`if (dropdown1.value == 1){
a.style.display = "";
b.style.display = "";
c.style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit sloppy, but here's one way to do it. You have an array of data with the valid secondary values per primary value. Then you render them each time the primary list changes.

```js
let dropdownlist = [];
dropdownlist[1] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
dropdownlist[2] = ['b', 'c'];

let select = document.createElement('select');

document.getElementById('myItemList').appendChild(select);

let x = 1;

document.getElementById('firstddl').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  //console.log(e.target.value);
  x = e.target.value;
  select.innerHTML = '';
  renderDDL(dropdownlist, x)

});

function renderDDL(dropdownlist, x) {
  dropdownlist[x].forEach(function(item) {
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    select.appendChild(option);

    option.innerHTML += item;
  });
}

renderDDL(dropdownlist, x); // Runs once
```

```html
<select id="firstddl">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>


<div id="myItemList">

</div>
```